# MSAccess - subForms of the same table

Tags: forms, ms-access, synchronization, subforms

Here's my scenario:

I have a a main table, Projects, with a o2m relationship to a second table Changes.  This second table is quite wide so I would like to be able to segment the information across several subforms on different tabs.

I've created a main form, the tabs and the subforms on each tab and the presentation is fine.  The problem comes when I create a new record.  On the first tab (containing subform1), I create a new record and fill in some values.  When I click on the second tab (subform2), the new record is not there.  My question is how can I keep the different subforms all in sync?

I've tried to do a Requery of subform 2 using the OnClick event on the second tab but to no avail.  I could be just doing that incorrectly.

Any ideas please?

Thanks,

Jon C

Comment: Show that you tried solving this yourself.

Comment: Are you sure you even need subforms? Why not just put some fields on a tab control.

Comment: Hi JohnFx, I need to show the multiple rows in the Changes tbl against each project so I don't think adding individual fields will help me.

Comment: Assuming the record has been committed to the DB in sf1 and sf2 is based on the same table then I can see no reason why a requery would not work.  Does moving to a different project and coming back then moving back to this project make the data visible in both subforms?

Comment: If I move to a different project and back it's fine.  Just to check, I have the requery on the OnClick event for the second tab (sf2).  Does that make sense as being the right place?